# What's this assembly code language? (decompliled code)

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I'm trying to understand a decompiled assembly code and I dont know what's its instruction set, does someone recognize this language? 
(OS: Windows, I think the original code was generated with a program  named GameMaker, the compiled file name is data.win)

Part of the code:

```
$00:        push.v    argument0
$08:        dup.v
$0C:        push.e    0
$10:        seq.i.v
$14:        bt    $00001DAC
$18:        dup.v
$1C:        push.e    1
$20:        seq.i.v
$24:        bt    $00001DB0
$28:        dup.v
$2C:        push.e    2
$30:        seq.i.v
$34:        bt    $00001E14
```

When reading this, I wonder what does .e/.v/.i/.s mean, it looks like ".e" indicates integer value, ".v" variable name and ".s" string value, but I would like to read documentation about it, I did't find anything googling.
Thanks!

Comment: That's most likely the textual representation of [Gamemaker bytecode](https://github.com/kvanberendonck/acolyte/wiki/Bytecode). So you'll have to look up what each instruction does on that page and use that to RE the code.

Comment: `I'm trying to understand a decompiled assembly code and I dont know what's its instruction set` -- But you did obtain this disassembly, so including how you obtained this might help...